# Computer Inverse Matrix of non-square matrix in CUDA

Tags: cuda, gpu, matrix-inverse

I am trying to find Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse of a non-square matrix in CUDA.

Today, I am using following code as an implementation of Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse.

https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/blob/75c3b9fbbfd3fa2def6780179006bde7ca343b08/src/Numerics/LinearAlgebra/Complex/Matrix.cs

**The problem is that the non-square matrix size I am trying to find pseudoinverse is rather big so I would like to solve it in using CUDA to harness the power of GPU.**

I am basically looking for CUDA version of this code

```
public static Matrix PseudoInverse(this Matrix M)
    {
        Svd<double> D = M.Svd(true);
        Matrix W = (Matrix)D.W;
        Vector s = (Vector)D.S;


        // The first element of W has the maximum value.
        double tolerance = Precision.EpsilonOf(2) * Math.Max(M.RowCount, M.ColumnCount) * W[0, 0];

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Count; i++)
        {
            if (s[i] < tolerance)
                s[i] = 0;
            else
                s[i] = 1 / s[i];
        }
        W.SetDiagonal(s);

        // (U * W * VT)T is equivalent with V * WT * UT
        return (Matrix)(D.U * W * D.VT).Transpose();

    }
```

- **Does anybody has any pointers on Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse implementation in CUDA.**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I would like to know what other ways might be there to solve Moore–Penrose pseudoinverse of a non-square matrix using GPU that's deployable.

Comment: That code doesn't calculate a matrix inverse. It calculates a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse. There is no such thing as an inverse matrix for a non-square matrix. By definition, they do not exist. But, whatever because this question is off-topic for [SO] and I have voted to close it

Comment: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/index.html#cuds-lt-t-gt-gesvd

Comment: This question is off-topic for [SO] and should never have been reopened.

Comment: Could you please enlighten why this shouldn't be in StackOverflow?

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I did implementing the Moore-Penrose pseudoinvese by using the SVD function of CUDA

http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusolver/#svd-example1

The only problem is that CUDA version of SVD is much slower than native MKL version! While solving the matrix size of 1000 x 1000, CUDA's SVD function is almost 4 times slower than MKL library's SVD function.

On a side note, I saw people claiming that CULA used to be much faster but isn't supported anymore. CULA is still provided commercially, but license cost about 25K per year.